# pandas dataframe How to sequence rows based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, sequence

I am trying to sequence an already sequenced dataset based on conditions. The dataframe looks like the following (the intended output is my desired output):

|  | id | activity | duration_sec | cycle | intended_cycle |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | start | 0.7 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | a | 0.3 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | b | 0.4 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | c | 0.5 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | c | 0.5 | 1 | 2 |
| 6 | 1 | d | 0.4 | 1 | 2 |
| 7 | 1 | e | 0.6 | 1 | 3 |
| 8 | 1 | stop | 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 9 | 1 | start | 0.1 | 2 | 4 |
| 10 | 1 | b | 0.3 | 2 | 4 |
| 11 | 1 | stop | 0.2 | 2 | 4 |
| 12 | 1 | f | 0.3 | 3 | 5 |
| 13 | 2 | stop | 40 | 4 | 6 |
| 14 | 2 | start | 3 | 5 | 7 |
| 15 | 2 | a | 0.7 | 5 | 7 |
| 16 | 2 | a | 3 | 5 | 7 |
| 17 | 2 | b | 0.2 | 5 | 7 |
| 18 | 2 | stop | 0.2 | 5 | 7 |
| 19 | 2 | start | 0.1 | 6 | 8 |
| 20 | 2 | f | 0.4 | 6 | 8 |
| 21 | 2 | g | 0.2 | 6 | 8 |
| 22 | 2 | h | 0.5 | 6 | 8 |
| 23 | 2 | h | 6 | 6 | 8 |
| 24 | 2 | stop | 9 | 6 | 8 |
| 25 | 2 | start | 0.2 | 7 | 9 |
| 26 | 2 | e | 0.3 | 7 | 9 |
| 27 | 2 | f | 0.4 | 7 | 10 |
| 28 | 2 | stop | 0.7 | 7 | 10 |

The alphabets are representative of activity names. I'm hoping to sequence as per the intended cycle column.  This is based on the condition that within the current sequence:

1. the first activity duration>0.5s after the "start", would be considered as 1 sequence (or a sub-sequence, if you will).

- the duplicate activities occurring consecutively will be considered as one if either value is >0.5s

2. the next activity that is >0.5s, after the first>0.5s would be considered as the next sequence

- if there is no more activity >0.5s after, the sequence will be considered till the cycle column value changes

3. if there is no activity within the current cycle that is >0.5s, the activities will be considered independent (i.e. row 25-28)

I'd really appreciate any help. Big thanks to there being a community for this!

```
sample code for df:
data = {'Unnamed: 0': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8, 8: 9, 9: 10, 10: 11, 11: 12, 12: 13, 13: 14, 14: 15, 15: 16, 16: 17, 17: 18, 18: 19, 19: 20, 20: 21, 21: 22, 22: 23, 23: 24, 24: 25, 25: 26, 26: 27, 27: 28}, 
        'id': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1, 9: 1, 10: 1, 11: 1, 12: 2, 13: 2, 14: 2, 15: 2, 16: 2, 17: 2, 18: 2, 19: 2, 20: 2, 21: 2, 22: 2, 23: 2, 24: 2, 25: 2, 26: 2, 27: 2}, 
        'activity': {0: 'start', 1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'c', 5: 'd', 6: 'e', 7: 'stop', 8: 'start', 9: 'b', 10: 'stop', 11: 'f', 12: 'stop', 13: 'start', 14: 'a', 15: 'a', 16: 'b', 17: 'stop', 18: 'start', 19: 'f', 20: 'g', 21: 'h', 22: 'h', 23: 'stop', 24: 'start', 25: 'e', 26: 'f', 27: 'stop'}, 
        'duration_sec': {0: 0.7, 1: 0.3, 2: 0.4, 3: 0.5, 4: 0.5, 5: 0.4, 6: 0.6, 7: 2.0, 8: 0.1, 9: 0.3, 10: 0.2, 11: 0.3, 12: 40.0, 13: 3.0, 14: 0.7, 15: 3.0, 16: 0.2, 17: 0.2, 18: 0.1, 19: 0.4, 20: 0.2, 21: 0.5, 22: 6.0, 23: 9.0, 24: 0.2, 25: 0.3, 26: 0.4, 27: 0.7}, 'cycle': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 2, 9: 2, 10: 2, 11: 3, 12: 4, 13: 5, 14: 5, 15: 5, 16: 5, 17: 5, 18: 6, 19: 6, 20: 6, 21: 6, 22: 6, 23: 6, 24: 7, 25: 7, 26: 7, 27: 7}, 'intended_cycle': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 2, 6: 3, 7: 3, 8: 4, 9: 4, 10: 4, 11: 5, 12: 6, 13: 7, 14: 7, 15: 7, 16: 7, 17: 7, 18: 8, 19: 8, 20: 8, 21: 8, 22: 8, 23: 8, 24: 9, 25: 9, 26: 10, 27: 10}}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

Comment: kindly post the expected output

Comment: the expected output is the intended cycle